# What is the meaning of the file names flanked by the '#' sign and how can I remove them?

Tags: raspberry-pi2

When I do the 'ls' command in the terminal on my Raspberry Pi 2, I see different types of names of files, some like "#example.cpp#", as well as others like "homework1.cpp~".

What do these two file types mean, and how can I get rid of them? Simply using the 'rm' command doesn't seem to be working for me. Thanks!

[image: Raspberry Pi Linux Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications will create a copy of a file and use special characters when creating the filename for the copy.  For instance some text editors will make a copy of a file you are starting to edit by using the same name and adding a tilde character (~) to the end of the file.  That way you will have a backup of the file that you are about to edit.

Another reason would be if an application is processing the file into a temporary file with the temporary file then being used for the next step. For example perhaps the C/C++ compiler is reading the file `homework1.cpp` with the C Preprocessor to generate the temporary file `#homework1.cpp#` which is then compiled by the compiler to generate the object code file.

I am not familiar with raspberry pi so am not sure as to what may be creating the filenames with the pound sign (#) on the front and back.  Perhaps it is the C++ compiler.  I am pretty sure the files with the tilde character on appended to the end of the file name is a back file from `vi` or `vim` containing a copy of the file at the time it was last opened with the text editor.

One thing that you could do is to look in those files to see what is there using a Linux command or a text editor. If you use a text editor I would copy the file to another folder as a back up and then look at it there.

Edit: Someone just posted and then deleted an answer which also mentioned about how to remove these files.

What I read was that the `rm` command is used however for some kinds of special characters you will need to use quotes around the name and you may also need to use an escape to escape certain special characters.

The command shell reads the command line you type in and makes changes to the text before passing it on to the command you type in.  So if the filename has a space in it, say `jj Johny` then when you remove the file you have to specify `rm "jj Johny"` since spaces are used by the command processor to separate out arguments.

The other poster mentioned that you had to escape out the pound sign (#) using the back slash character in order to prevent it from being modified by the command processor.